# Drawing a bitmap directly to an X11 window

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm working on a software renderer, and I need a way to draw the resulting bitmap to an X11 window. On Windows I'm drawing the bitmap directly to a window using `StretchDIBits`. Is there any similar way to do it using XLib?

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759604/drawing-to-x11-root-window), but I'm wondering how to go about updating the pixmap every frame? Deleting it and creating a new one each frame seems like it would be slow.

Comment: "seems like it would be slow." You should measure it, then decide if it will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering updating in realtime a bitmap, then you should operate in the server, and make the server do the modifications for  you.  Or just request a pixmap extension (in the form of some shared memory segment between server and client) and limit yourself to run client and server on the same machine (in a way that they both, share the frame buffer memory).  X11 is basically a network protocol, so anything you have to update on your pixmap (a pixmap is an object that resides in the server side) has to go over a network connection and so, is subject to network delivery delays.